# How to export contentful ERD

Tags: erd, contentful

I want to make ER diagram of my contentful space.Is there a way for the same .There is a option to get the table structure in JSON format .

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box feature to get your content structure in an ER format. You could however easily pull down your entire content structure in JSON by making a request similar to this:

```
https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/YOURSPACE/content_types/?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN
```

This would result in a JSON response with your entire content type structure and you could then parse this into an ER model however you please.

If you specifically want the JSON-schema for entries, content types etc. they are available in the documentation that you can find here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api.

Just click on the sample for any request and there's a small button to show the JSON schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same issue came up for me recently. I also didn't find a satisfactory answer. So I wrote my own solution. The [contentful-plantuml-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-plantuml-generator) executable converts a space's content model to a PlantUML diagram.

After installing it and `plantuml`. You can use it like this:

```
contentful-plantuml-generator <SPACE_ID> <ACCESS_TOKEN> \
  | plantuml -pipe -tsvg \
  > my-diagram.svg
```